# How to execute a function based off another functions success or failure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

I have a main function that searches a txt file with 2 keywords from user input, if it finds it then it will print the line in the txt file.

I want to write another function (send_email) that executes if the main function doesn't find anything in the file that matches, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def main_function():
  with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
      if line.startswith(area) and name in line:
        print("\n" + "\n" + "SPP Location:" + "\n" + line + "\n")

main_function()



def send_email():
  blah blah blah


if main_function is False:
   send_email
```

Comment: Return a value from the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by setting a flag. If you loop through file and you did not find match then flag stay false.

```
def main_function():
  with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    find_flag = False
    for line in f.readlines():
      if line.startswith(area) and name in line:
        print("\n" + "\n" + "SPP Location:" + "\n" + line + "\n")
        find_flag = True
    if not find_flag:
        send_email()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the success of a match in a variable and call the function if the variable hasn't change due a match:

```
def main_function():
    with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
        results = 0
        for line in f.readlines():
            if line.startswith(area) and name in line:
                print("\n" + "\n" + "SPP Location:" + "\n" + line + "\n")
                results = 1
        if results == 0:
            send_email()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. There's no need to call main_function separately. It will be called when you evaluate the condition "not main_function()".

```
def main_function():
    with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if line.startswith(area) and name in line:
                print("\n" + "\n" + "SPP Location:" + "\n" + line + "\n")
                return True
    return False

def send_email():
    blah blah blah


if not main_function():
    send_email()
```

Comment: In your code only one line (maximum) is printed, but in the code in the question if there are multiple matches they will all be printed.

Answer (score -1):

How about the following script:

```
try:
    main_function
except:
    send_email
```

This way, if the main_function function throws an error, python will catch it, and call the send_email function.

Alternatively, if you are not expecting main_function to fail by throwing an error, you could do the following:

```
def main_function():
  
  success = False
  
  with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
      if line.startswith(area) and name in line:
        print("\n" + "\n" + "SPP Location:" + "\n" + line + "\n")
        
        success = True
  
  return success

def send_email():
  blah blah blah

main_function_success = main_function()

if not main_function_success:
   send_email
```

Comment: `if main_function is False:` is wrong, and although it comes originally from the question, you need to correct it.

Comment: @alaniwi My bad. It's fixed now!

Comment: Now you are calling `main_function` twice, and also the question says that email is to be sent if a match is _not_ found.

Comment: @alaniwi Whoops. Fixed again!